# Using pointer to print each element in a string by C++

Tags: c++, pointers

I am currently working on a question, which uses a string input, then output each element in this string for example:
input: "abcd"
output: "a", "b", "c", "d"

I know there are some easy ways to solve this problem, but I am trying to use a pointer, my idea is simple, find a pointer points to the initial char of the string, as each memory address only store 1 byte of the element which is 1 char in each address, then I iterate through the string and print each of then by pointer arithmetic, I use following code:

```
char* ptr = (char *) inputstring.c_str();
```

to find the initial address of the first element, then I use pointer arithmetic to move to the next element in the string

```
ptr = (char *) (ptr + 1);
```

but it returns something like:
input: "abcd"
output: "abcd", "bcd", "cd", "d"

which really confuse me, as char * should only point to a single char element right?

following is my whole code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

void printStr(const string& inputstring){

    int length = inputstring.length();
    char* ptr = (char *) inputstring.c_str();

    for(int i = 1; i <= length; i++){

        printf("%c\n", *ptr);
        ptr = (char *) (ptr + 1);

    }

}

int main(){

    string a = "abcd";

    printStr(a);


}
```

sorry, as the compiler's issue, I couldn't find a hidden bug in my code, now I have solved it by adding * to ptr, thanks for helping again.

Comment: In case you are thinking of growing this, it is worth taking note that unicode strings are not single byte characters.  You would be far better off implementing a class and encapsulating whatever features you need there.

Comment: @LuCC Using this call printf("%c\n", *ptr); you can not get the output you showed in your question.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow yes that what I did, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you print a char* - while it DOES point to just a single character, you're actually telling the function to keep going until it gets to a null terminating character.

ie - your string is actually "a" "b" "c" "d" "\0"

Since the null is just a little further down, it prints all the way to the end; and then you do the same, just starting a 1 character further forward.

If you want it to just print a single character, then you want to dereference the pointer (with the * operator), to get the single character.  ie
`print(*ptr)`